# Download Source and then Extract a Value from an ID

Tags: vb.net

How can I download a Webpage's source and then extract a value of an ID, which then inputs that into a Text box?

```
        <div class='stats'>
                <h3>Current Guide Price <span title='2,506,909'>    2.5m
```

So, The above Code Snippet is from an actual Webpage. I can Successfully download the Source of the webpage, but i would like to get the value of 2,506,900 and then export that 2,506,900 to a Text box.

EDIT: What I Have Now (Not Much)

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/Runescape/viewitem?obj=4151")
        MessageBox.Show(sourceString)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I Just now updated the Post To Include what I have now.

Comment: That's not much of an attempt is it? You likely need a HTML parser, or you might be able to get away with using regular expressions.

Comment: @ADyson and how can i do a HTML Parser. It's not that i didn't attempt it much.. it is that i am not familar with VB.net Code and The Tutorials i keep seeing in Google are years old.

Comment: you would be best to find a 3rd party library which can already do the job. [See here](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+html+parser)

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the HTML code from vb.net is something you can easily find on internet. One such code is below :

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com")
using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim htmlCode As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        ' htmlCode variable holds the HTML code of the web page. 
    End Using
End Using
```

Now, what remains is the parsing of the code. You can use the div class or text on the screen. One way is to find the string within string. Example :

```
Dim searchStartString = "Current Guide Price <span title"
Dim searchEndString = "="
Dim position As Integer = htmlCode.IndexOf(searchStartString) + searchStartString + 1
dim endPosition as Integer = htmlCode.IndexOf(searchEndString,position)

Dim requiredString = htmlCode.substr(position,endPosition-position)
```

Note : You'll have to add offsets as required (typically +1 or -1 or like). And the above code is not unit tested. You might have to do a minor adjustment(s). Use this code more as a guideline than full-fledged implementation.